# FullCalendar: How to find resources that are Expanded

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I can't seem to find a way in React FullCalendar to get all resources that are expanded. You can set a resource to be expanded or not expanded using calendarAPI:

```
calendarApi.currentDataManager.dispatch({
          type: "SET_RESOURCE_ENTITY_EXPANDED",
          id: resource.id,
          isExpanded: expanded,
        });
```

but how can we get the resources' expanded states?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. If you'd like to expand/collapse all resources, you can iterate through the resource list, dispatching the expand event for each (see below).

```
//import the api
import { CalendarApi } from '@fullcalendar/common';

//add as an override to calendar api (not necessary to override, can be wrapped in a plain function)
CalendarApi.prototype.expandResources = function (expanded) {

    //fetch all resources from api
    var resources = this.getResources();
    
    //iterate through each resource, sending a dispatch event for each
    for(var resource of resources){
        this.dispatch({
            type: 'SET_RESOURCE_ENTITY_EXPANDED',
            id: resource.id,
            isExpanded: expanded,
        });
    }     
};
```